# GWAN as embeded server for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, g-wan

not sure if this is possible but was wondering if its possible to embed GWAN in spring boot app (like tomcat/jetty etc.) are.  and how so?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the [Spring Boot documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) tells, the requirements are to package your G-WAN application as a jar (zip) file, and install and configure **Spring plugins** to connect the dots.

One of them, **Gradle**, takes `50.5 MB` to let you use several programming languages: *"Gradle makes the impossible possible, the possible easy and the easy elegant."*

G-WAN delivers [even more language mix](http://www.gwan.ch/developers#servlet) in `200 KB` of code. G-WAN works without configuration files, nor it needs any war archives to be built, and deployed each time you edit the code of a Java G-WAN script. G-WAN's philosophy is real-time *"edit & play"*.

With some adjustments, it will be possible to use G-WAN with in a **Spring Boot application**, but thats' like trying to attach a lorry trailer to a formula one: are the expected gains worth the exercise?

If you see advantages at adding this much `code, configuration and maintenance overhead` to G-WAN, could you please try to enumerate them?

If you are an advanced Spring developer and you still believe that there's value in this proposition, we will help you by adapting G-WAN wherever needed, providing you or other Spring experts can tell what must be done.